# Get the properties of an asp.button function in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I would like to know how I can get the properties of an asp:Button from a javascript function.

Specifically I want to be able to test whether a specific aspx button is enabled or not in a javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the client ID of the `<asp:Button />` you can use `document.getElementById` function to get the reference of it's DOM object and get other properties you are interested in.
An example:

Some where in aspx mark up:

```
<asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me"/>
```

In javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //button1 is the ID of asp:Button
    var objButton = document.getElementById('<%=button1.ClientID');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this like you would with a plain html button.

```
<asp:Button id="foo" runat="server" />
```

Turns into

```
<input type="button" id="foo" />
```

If youre using a new version of asp.net, you can add ClientIDMode="Static" so that the id doesnt change to something else.